# How to update Flutter frontend when updates to Rest API

Tags: rest, http, flutter, frontend

This might seem like a stupid question and it probably is but here is it anyway:
I have a `Flutter` frontend of let's say a shopping list. All the contents of the page are from a `REST API` I built in `Spring` (interfacing with `MongoDB`) but how can I update the flutter f-e when someone deletes one of the item on the shopping list (through a HTTP request) automatically. It'd be great if the solution wouldn't require the user manually reloading the page or having to check if the JSON content I get back from a request is the same every 20 seconds or so.
I'd love to hear if there's a way to do so!

Comment: You have to implement sockets.

Comment: As @delmin said, you will need to use sockets or another method that allows real-time data flow. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet

Comment: @GregoryConrad thank you for the link! I'll look into it  and let y'all know how it goes